# Sleep as Android with Tasker and Spotify

Tags: android, spotify, sleep, alexa-skills-kit, tasker

i use sleep as android as my alarm in the morning and it would be nice that i can play a playlist on my Amazon Alexa when the alarm starts.
I allready tried something which looks like this:
The profile for the morning routine
[image: Tasker]
The Wakeup Task which calls the other tasks and works fine
[image: Wakeuptask which calls other tasks]
The Spotify Task which works.
[image: Spotify Task]
My Problem is that when the alarm triggers the task somehow tasker wont start Spotify...
I think the problem ist that the alarm triggers the task, overlays its anti sleep captcha and AutoInput cant click on Spotify anymore...
A solution would be that the task gets triggeret half a minute before the alarm or spotify gets handled in the background. But i dont know how to do this so i would be thankful for any suggestion.